# Is it possible to characterize the sign of the trace and det at the fixed points of a dynamical system using Gröbner, postponing computing the points?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, groebner-bases

Here is an example of a dynamical system for which the isoclines may intersect at two or more points (under certain numeric conditions). It is easy to compute the trace and determinant of the *Jacobian* at the two fixed points numerically in particular instances:

```
X = {s, i}; par = {Λ, β, βr, γ, ν, sd};
cp = Thread[
  par > 0]; ss = Λ (1 - 
     s/sd) - (β - ν) s i; ifac = 
 s (β - βr) - 
  i (βr - ν) + βr - (Λ + γ +  ν);
dyn = {ss, i ifac};

Column@dyn
jac = Simplify@D[dyn, {X}];
tr = Tr@jac; det = Det[jac];

(*interior fixed points*)
ee = Solve[{ifac == 0, ss == 0}, X] // FullSimplify;
cn = Thread[par -> {1/100, 2/10, 4/10, 7/100, 15/100, 95/100}];

Print["trace and det at first interior fixed point are"]
{t1, d1} = {tr, det} /. ee[[1]] /. cn // FullSimplify // N
Print["trace and det at second interior fixed point are"]
{t2, d2} = {tr, det} /. ee[[2]] /. cn // FullSimplify // N
```

However, computing the fixed points symbolically is often very hard, and it would be nice if one could avoid it or at least postpone it to one last numerical operation. My  try of eliminating with Gröbner bases seems to produce an answer which does not reveal its connection to the two fixed points, as pointed out by @user293787

```
Print["trace and det at  fixed points after Groebner ?"]
trg = GroebnerBasis[{ss, ifac, tr}, par, X][[1]];
detg = GroebnerBasis[{ss, ifac, det}, par, X][[1]];
{trg, detg} /. cn // N
```

In this case, one may investigate by eliminating s explicitly, in two ways in fact. For both eliminations, the result ("Hopf bifurcation polynomial") is essentially `trg` up to proportionality constants

```
Print["explicit s formulas from first and sec eqs are"]
cs = Flatten[Solve[dyn[[1]] == 0, s]]
cs2 = Flatten[Solve[(dyn[[2]]/i) == 0, s]]
poli = Numerator[Together[(dyn[[2]]/i) /. cs]] // FullSimplify;
Print["first Hopf polynomial formula"]
tri1 = Collect[Numerator[Together[tr /. cs]] // Factor, i];
res1 = Resultant[poli, tri1, i] // Factor
Print["has" , Length[res1], " factors"]
Print["second Hopf polynomial formula"]
tri2 = Collect[Numerator[Together[tr /. cs2]], i];
res2 = Resultant[poli, tri2, i] // Factor
Print["has" , Length[res2], " factors"]
Print["both contain trg(trace by Groebner); after dividing by trg, \
proportionality constants are"]
{res1/trg, res2/trg} // Simplify
```

I am rather lost as to how we can exploit the eliminated `{trg, detg}` for analyzing the stability of the dynamical system. The easiest application could be finding Bogdanov-Takens points. I revisit here Eduardo's example from Bazykin,  which seems to illustrate a whole curve of Bogdanov points. I modified the program by adding the positivity condition from the beginning

```
PredatorPrey[{x_, y_}][{\[Gamma]_, \[Epsilon]_, 
   n_}] := {x (1 - 
      y) - \[Epsilon] x^2, -\[Gamma] y + (y/(n + y)) x y}
X = {x, y}; \[Mu] = {\[Gamma], \[Epsilon], n}; Xp = 
 Flatten[Join[X, \[Mu]]]; cp = Thread[Xp > 0];
J[{x_, y_}][{\[Gamma]_, \[Epsilon]_, n_}] := 
 Simplify[Evaluate@D[PredatorPrey[X][\[Mu]], {X}]]
so = Factor@
  Solve[Join[{PredatorPrey[X][\[Mu]] == 0 && Tr[J[X][\[Mu]]] == 0 && 
      Det[J[X][\[Mu]]] == 0}, cp], {x, y, \[Gamma], \[Epsilon], n}]
J[X][\[Mu]] /. so /. y -> 1/4 // MatrixForm
{Tr[J[X][\[Mu]]], Det[J[X][\[Mu]]]} /. so /. y -> 1/5
```

and two checks at the end that any 0<y<1/2 yields a ''candidate of Bogdanov point".
This example with only 3 parameters runs very quickly (mine had 7). Back to my example, it is possible to find  Bogdanov points (candidates) by the method suggested by Eduardo of  Exchanging two parameters by the coords of one fixed point.

```
X = {s, i}; par = {\[CapitalLambda], \[Beta], \[Beta]r, \[Gamma], \
\[Nu], sd}; parX = Flatten[Join[par, X]];
cp = Join[
  Thread[par > 0], {sd <= 
    1}]; ss = \[CapitalLambda] (1 - 
     s/sd) - (\[Beta] - \[Nu]) s i; ifac = 
 s (\[Beta] - \[Beta]r) - 
  i (\[Beta]r - \[Nu]) + \[Beta]r - (\[CapitalLambda] + \[Gamma] + \
\[Nu]);
dyn = {ss, i ifac};
jac = Simplify@D[dyn, {X}];
tr = Tr@jac; det = Det[jac];
(*Exchange two parameters by coords of one fixed point*)
 s = s0; i = i0;
Print["Reparametrization by one fixed point"]
cC = Thread[{\[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]} -> 
   Flatten[Map[FullSimplify, 
      Map[Map[Numerator, #, {2}] &, 
       SolveValues[dyn == 0, {\[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}]], {2}]/
     Map[Map[Denominator, #, {2}] &, 
      SolveValues[dyn == 0, {\[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda]}]]]]
Print["Explicit second fixed point"]
Clear[s, i];
fp = Solve[Thread[(dyn /. cC) == 0], X][[3]] // FullSimplify
{s1, i1} = {s, i} /. fp;
Print["trace and det at second fixed point, after reparametrization"]
{trf, detf} = {tr, det} /. cC /. fp // FullSimplify
Print["Condition for Bogdanov point"]
re = Reduce[Join[{detf == 0, trf == 0}, {0 < s0 < 1, 0 < i0 < 1}, cp],
    Drop[par, {1, 4}]] // FullSimplify
par0 = Join[par, {s0, i0}];
Print["Find example and plot its isoclines"]
Timing[fi = 
  FindInstance[
   Join[{re}, cp, {\[Beta]r != \[Nu] && \[Beta] != \[Nu]}], par0]]
Print["check trace and det"]
{trf, detf} /. fi // N
Print["The two fixed points for Bogdanov must be equal"]
{{s0, i0}, {s1, i1}} /. fi // N
xm = .25; xM = (sd /. fi)[[1]];
iso = ContourPlot[{(ifac /. cC /. fi) == 0}, {s, xm, xM}, {i, 0, 1}];
pl = Plot[
   Evaluate[(SolveValues[ss == 0, i][[1]]) /. cC /. fi], {s, xm, 
    xM}];
Show[pl, iso]
Print["check discriminant"]
dis = 4 sd^2 (\[Beta] - \[Beta]r) \[CapitalLambda] (\[Beta] - \[Nu]) \
(\[Beta]r - \[Nu]) + (\[CapitalLambda] (\[Beta]r - \[Nu]) - 
     sd (\[Beta] - \[Nu]) (-\[Beta]r + \[Gamma] + \[CapitalLambda] + \
\[Nu]))^2;
dis /. cC /. fi
```

The suggested result, that discriminant=0 is necessary for Bogdanov here, is plausible. Unfortunately, this reparametrization method works probably only when we have two fixed interior points, and it would be very useful to achieve the result via Groebner !

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand what you want to do, but suppose I take `example={\[CapitalLambda]->-349,\[Beta]->29/10,\[Beta]r->5659,\[Gamma]->6065,\[Nu]->2904,sd->-((27550 (-14805+Sqrt[21790135]))/82635621)}` and `point={i->(-45113796+2755 Sqrt[21790135])/79925305,s->(27550 (-14805-Sqrt[21790135]))/1640891171}`. Then `gr/.example//Simplify` gives zero, so your condition holds, `{ss,ifac}/.point/.example//Simplify` gives `{0,0}`, so a critical point, but the trace `tr/.point/.example//Simplify` is not zero.

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed lost as to the meaning of the {trg, detg} obtained from  {tr, det} by Groebner  elimination

Comment: Your GB computations are in effect setting trace or det to 0. This is not what you want. Try instead for example `trg = GroebnerBasis[{ss, ifac, trace - tr}, Join[{trace}, par], 
   X][[1]]`. You can then solve for `trace`:`In[310]:= NSolve[trg == 0 /. cn, trace]

Out[310]= {{trace -> -0.139627}, {trace -> -0.0222674}}`

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau My question was missing the key word SIGN of trace and det, which are precisely what we want for stability analysis. So, the "varieties", ie the locus where the tr and det are 0, are not that far.  The ''universal stability solver" could be Timing[re = Reduce[Join[{detg > 0, trg < 0}, cp], par]], but I fear this computation may never end. An easier one could be Timing[re = Reduce[Join[{detg == 0, trg == 0}, cp], par]], the so called Bogdanov point

Comment: If you want to set trace and/or det to zero to demarcate the stability region then you have one or two variables too many in the parameter set, that is, assigning the values you use in `cn` makes the system overdetermined. Which is why `{trg, detg} /. cn // N ` gives nonzero results.

Answer (score 5):

My answer does not answer your doubts regarding the Groebner basis, but consider that it is an option to the problem of obtaining non-trivial equilibria.

A viable option is to `Set` the equilibrium coordinates and `Solve` the system for a couple of parameters. For example, when $s=1/5$ and $i=2/5$ (can be generic values $s_0$, $i_0$) we obtain the following

```
s = 1/5; i = 2/5;
Thread[{γ, Λ} -> Flatten[Map[FullSimplify, Map[Map[Numerator, #, {2}] &, SolveValues[dyn == 0, {γ, Λ}]], {2}]/Map[Map[Denominator, #, {2}] &, SolveValues[dyn == 0, {γ, Λ}]]]]
(*{γ -> ((-1 + 3 sd) β + 2 (-1 + 5 sd) βr + (3 - 13 sd) ν)/(5 (-1 + 5 sd)), Λ -> (2 sd (β - ν))/(5 (-1 + 5 sd))}*)
```

Then `Clear` $s$ and $i$ and `Set` what you get to γ and Λ. This is what we do when moving the parameters looking for the intersection of the zero-isoclines, but taking advantage of the fact that you can `Solve` in a simpler way for the parameters.

```
Clear[s,i]
γ = ((-1 + 3 sd) β + 2 (-1 + 5 sd) βr + (3 - 13 sd) ν)/(5 (-1 + 5 sd)); Λ = (2 sd (β - ν))/(5 (-1 + 5 sd));
Simplify@Solve[dyn == 0, X]
(*{{s -> 1/5, i -> 2/5}, {s -> (2 sd (-βr + ν))/((-1 + 5 sd) (β - βr)), i -> (β - 5 sd β + (-3 + 5 sd) βr + 2 ν)/(5 (-1 + 5 sd) (βr - ν))}}*)
```

Next, it is advisable to use parameter changes to explicitly handle the constraints (inequalities) that result from the assumption that the parameters are positive. For example, `β = β0 + ν` to handle the constraint `β - ν>0`, and so on for all constraints that appear.

Indeed, @florin, calculating the equilibrium points symbolically is usually very difficult, but this happens because we forget that the parameters also exist and that when we solve for parameters, restrictions usually appear that make it easier for us to obtain the equilibrium points.

At equilibrium $(1/5,2/5)$ there is a double Bogdanov-Takens point for the parameters $s_d$ and $β$.

**Florin's question**: Why shift parameters instead of just adding inequalities, say β - ν>0, to `Solve`?

To answer your question, let me demonstrate about the degeneracy of a Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation in an ecological model (nonlinear predator reproduction and prey competition) studied by [Bazykin et al., 1980 - page 50](https://doi.org/10.1142/2284).

The model:
$$\begin{eqnarray} 
&&\dot{x}=x (1-y)-\epsilon x^2\\
&&\dot{y}=\frac{x y^2}{n+y}-\gamma y
\end{eqnarray} 
$$

```
PredatorPrey[{x_, y_}][{γ_, ϵ_, n_}] := {x (1 - y) - ϵ x^2, -γ y + (y/(n + y)) x y}
X = {x, y};
μ = {γ, ϵ, n};
```

Jacobian matrix:

```
J[{x_, y_}][{γ_, ϵ_, n_}] :=Simplify[Evaluate@D[PredatorPrey[X][μ], {X}]]
```

We look for a Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation point by solving for $x$, $\gamma$, $\epsilon$ and $n$:

```
Factor@SolveValues[PredatorPrey[X][μ] == 0 && Tr[J[X][μ]] == 0 && Det[J[X][μ]] == 0, {x, γ, ϵ, n}]
(*{{(-1 + y)^3/(y (-1 + 2 y)), (-1 + y)^2/y, -((y (-1 + 2 y))/(-1 + y)^2), -(y^2/(-1 + 2 y))}}*)
```

The restriction here is over the predator population and is given by the following inequality:

$$
0<y<\frac{1}{2}
$$

Shifting the predator population and solving again:

```
Factor[SolveValues[PredatorPrey[X][μ] == 0 && Tr[J[X][μ]] == 0 && Det[J[X][μ]] == 0, {x, γ, ϵ, n}] /. y -> y0/(2 (1 + y0))]
(*{{(2 + y0)^3/(4 y0 (1 + y0)), (2 + y0)^2/(2 y0 (1 + y0)), (2 y0)/(2 + y0)^2, y0^2/(4 (1 + y0))}}*)
```

The Bogdanov-Takens point is given by:

```
X0 = {(2 + y0)^3/(4 y0 (1 + y0)), y0/(2 (1 + y0))}; μ0 = {(2 + y0)^2/(2 y0 (1 + y0)), (2 y0)/(2 + y0)^2, y0^2/(4 (1 + y0))};
Eigenvalues[Simplify@J[X0][μ0]];
(*{0, 0}*)
```

The resulting quadratic coefficients of the Bogdanov-Takens normal form are:

```
{a -> -((2 + y0)^2/(2 y0 (1 + y0))), b -> (-2 + y0)/y0}
```

It is clear that the degeneracy occurs for $y_0=2$, that is, at the point:

```
X0 /. y0 -> 2
(*{8/3, 1/3}*)
μ0 /. y0 -> 2
(*{4/3, 1/4, 1/3}*)
```

*The above point is reported by Bazykin. However, he does many things to prove it. This is why shifts in parameters and state variables are very useful.*

**Florin's doubt about Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation**:

I didn't look at the trace and the determinant, I just noticed that the coordinates of their equilibria are less than one; considering the values you assigned to the parameters. However, I think we can do more to show what happens with the Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation in that model.

Comment: Thanks for the nice trick, which achieves placing one of the fixed points at a chosen arbitrary place :) I have doubts about this added equilibrium being  Bogdanov-Takens, which would mean that you chose it not arbitrarily :) Concerning the constraints, I never forget them, but sometimes adding the proper inequalities (say det >0 for Hopf bif) increases considerably the execution time, so it may be reasonable  to remember them later. Finally, why shift parameters instead of just adding inequalities, say β - ν>0, to Solve?

Comment: First, let me answer your question, and then the matter of the Bogdanov-Takens bifurcation. :)

Comment: Dear Eduardo see added  comments in the question, on the Bazykin example.  I guess your comments are related more to the computation of the normal form; we could  maybe exchange more on this privately:)

Answer (score 0):

This question was not  formulated clearly enough. The now maybe evident answer which emerged after the discussions is that the variety generated by trg==0 (trg = GroebnerBasis[{ss, ifac, tr}, par, X][[1]]) is the union of the varieties generated by t[i] ==0, where t[i] is the trace evaluated   at the i-th (interior) fixed point. So, Groebner may be used graphically to produce a superset of the sets we need, but separating this variety into branches is impossible, without explicitizing the branches (this is similar to the answer of @Daniel Lichtblau )