# When 'GroebnerBasis' is used for eliminating the state variables in determinant of Jacobian, is the sign related to the signs of det at fix points?

Tags: differential-equations, groebner-bases

Elimination is typically very difficult without  Mathematica,  for nonlinear dynamical systems, for example when one must find the Determinant at the fixed points. With Mathematica, this seems achievable both by 'Eliminate', and  by 'GroebnerBasis'.  The latter is supposed to be more general, but for me, it's full scope is harder to understand.  The next program  eliminates the fixed points coords (s,i) from the determinant of a Jacobian via Groebner

```
sp = \[CapitalLambda] - s \[CapitalLambda] + i s (-\[Beta] + \[Nu]);
    ifa = s \[Beta] - \[Gamma] - \[CapitalLambda] - \[Nu] + i \[Nu]; ip = 
     i ifa; 
    dyn = {sp, ip};
    X = {s, i}; par = {\[Beta], \[Gamma], \[CapitalLambda],\[Nu]}; jac = 
     Grad[dyn, X]; jac // MatrixForm
    Print["determinant"]
    det = Det[jac] // FullSimplify
    Print["endemic det by Groebner"]
    detG = GroebnerBasis[{sp, ip, det}, par, X][[1]] // FullSimplify
    detG2 = GroebnerBasis[{det, sp, ip}, par, X][[1]] // FullSimplify;
detG/detG2
```

The last command shows that the sign of detG is unaffected by the position of det within the command.

In this easy case, we can also obtain  sharper results, separating the manifold detG=0 in its three branches.
Here is branch 2.

```
Print["endemic det by sequential elim"]
cs = Flatten[Solve[dyn[[1]] == 0, s]]
ci = Flatten[Solve[(dyn[[2]] /. cs) == 0, i] // FullSimplify]
dets = det //. cs /. ci[[2]]
Timing[FindInstance[dets == 0 && detG > 0, par]]
```

The last failed 'FindInstance' seems to confirm that the sequential elimination  yields a branch of detG=0.

@user293787  suggests an interesting theorem:
`detG /Times@@(det/.Solve[{sp,ip}==0,{s,i}])`equals "some normalization constant". The only special thing about the det  is that it is a function of the Jacobian, so maybe this conjecture holds also true for any function f(jac). For the det, the quotient of these two quantities, obtained by

```
ds = (det /. Solve[{sp, ip} == 0, {s, i}]);
pds = Times @@ ds // FullSimplify
detG/pds // FullSimplify
```

is very simple, just \frac{\nu  (\beta -\nu )}{\Lambda },  considerably simpler than the quantities involved.

Comment: Could you not use a more minimal example such as `GroebnerBasis[{x+u,y+u},{x,y},u]` versus `Eliminate[{x+u==0,y+u==0},u]` to ask your question?

Comment: @user293787 This question is related to both  differential equations and to algebra.  Let me try to formalize it  this time, not by example. We have one special expression, for example a two by two determinant det, and we want to eliminate m  of its variables, using m equations. The minimal interesting dimension seems to me m=2, like in my example.  On top of this, I want that the quantity det for which I reduce the number of variables does not change sign outside the variety det=0. In your example, there is a symmetry between x+u and y +u which worries me. So, maybe this example is confusing?

Comment: Could some form of PolynomialReduce achieve this?

Comment: As Daniel Lichtblau wrote [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271578), you effectively set `det` equal to zero when writing `detG = GroebnerBasis[{...,det,...},...]`. Approximately speaking, your `detG` has the following meaning: its vanishing locus are parameter values for which there exists a fixed point `{s,i}` at which the determinant `det` of the Jacobian vanishes. In fact, `detG` is closely related to the product of the determinants of the Jacobians at the fixed points, as one can see by evaluating that product: `Times@@(det/.Solve[{sp,ip}==0,{s,i}])//FullSimplify`.

Comment: @user293787 you suggest an interesting theorem: detG /Times@@(det/.Solve[{sp,ip}==0,{s,i}]) equals "some normalization constant". The only   special thing about the det here is that it is a function of the Jacobian, so maybe this conjecture could  true for any function f(jac). I'll be checking this. For now, I'll add this fascinating conjecture to the question, with proper citation :)

Comment: If I follow correctly, in this computation the determinant is forced to vanish at certain points. So it must be divisible by the determinant when evaluated at each of those points.

Comment: Yes, and this is an interesting trick, because this ``Groebner determinant" of the Jacobian forced to vanish at all the fixed points of a dynamical system turns out to be much simpler than the determinant  at one fixed point. The first might be one line long, and the second one page. And the product of several pages results in one line :)

Comment: I wonder if it is a case of having roots that are algebraic conjugates, so determinants evaluated at individual roots give "large" results but their product is simpler?

Comment: Something like that, the Vieta relations between the roots which determine i must simplify somehow the expressions (even for higher order polynomials in i). I am trying now to check if the same thing happens for the trace (trG), but either the product identity of  
@user293787 is wrong, or I'm making silly mistakes (more likely :)

Answer (score 5):

I do not know what OP means by "right sign". But to get a canonical normalization, one can rescale the polynomial and set the [leading coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis) equal to $1$. For example, define

```
leadingCoefficient[poly_,vars_]:=First[MonomialList[poly,vars]]/.Thread[vars->1];
normalize[poly_,vars_]:=poly/leadingCoefficient[poly,vars];
```

This is an adaptation of code [in this 1996 paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228598800_Grobner_bases_in_Mathematica_30) by Daniel Lichtblau.

Then

```
normalize[detG,par]-normalize[detE,par] // Expand
(* 0 *)
```

which shows that both have the same normalization.

**Note.** All this is for Mathematica's default monomial order (Lexicographic).

Comment: Just a remark for readers: OP edited the question considerably. This answer was in response to the original question [available here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/272061/1). The definitions of `detG`, `detE`, `par` can be found there.

Comment: detG and par are still defined in the new version. I have removed detE = Collect[dete[[1]] - dete[[2]], \[Beta]], which was a parallel implementation of the same question using Eliminate. My original question was also on whether these two commands are essentially equivalent, and if so, why does Mathematica offer both of them? It seems this only slows down users, because they need to figure out what works quicker, or is better documented. It seems Groebner is the winner on both, so I withdrew half of my question (also detE is  rather arbitrarily defined,  dete[[2]] - dete[[1]] is also possible)

Comment: Concerning the two alternative eliminations, I have obtained in a more complicated example Timing of Groebner (detG) =13.4844 and Timing of Eliminate (detE) 3175.61. Maybe Eliminate for polynomial questions should be implemented via Groebner?

Comment: To respond, yes, `Eliminate` should be reimplemented using `GroebnerBasis`. It's on my eternity list.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the conclusion of these discussions is that:

1. The easiest quantities to obtain symbolically for bifurcation analysis of dynamical systems are `Prod_i Det(Jac(E_i))' and` Prod_i Tr(Jac(E_i))', where the product  runs  over all the fixed points.
2. These products may be obtained via `GroebnerBasis` elimination, as shown in the example.
   (1-2) are probably not as well-known as they should be, both in the algebra, and in the dynamical systems communities (please, prove me wrong by references :)
3. The command `Eliminate` may be much slower than  `GroebnerBasis` elimination.